# Access CSV files on a SharePoint folder with multiple Authentication using python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I have a number of csv files on a SharePoint folder of my company. We need to give Mail id followed by username and password to login SharePoint i.e. multiple authentication.

I tried to use many libraries but nothing work as most of use only username and password to login.

I also tried to get login using selenium, i successful login in SharePoint folder but don't know how to read content of csv files attached on that particular folder

please share if someone have nay idea to get access csv file saved on SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to click on the file and download it? If so you could use

> import csv

Then you use code like this to read from the csv

```
with open(csvFile) as file:
    csvReader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\n')
    for obj in csvReader:
        data.append(obj[0]) #or whatever you need to do with the text
```

Comment: I tried it, but unable to find csv on SharePoint webpage as i login in multi authenticate SharePoint using selenium.